# why use `not not` operation?

Tags: lua

In the following Lua code:

```
function eq_event(op1, op2)
    if op1 == op2 then
        return true
    end
    local h = getequalhandler(op1, op2)
    if h then
        return not not h(op1, op2)
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

why use `not not` before the return value? is it different with the raw return value? I also remember that in C, there also got chance to use the `!!` before some expression, does them the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`not not` will convert nil into false, and all other values except `false` to `true`. You may need to return a boolean value only when interacting with C.

Yes it's the same as `!!` in C. Only difference is that in C, 0 (and some other values I don't remember) is also falsy (that is, they'll return false when doubled not'd).

Comment: In Lua, both `false` and `nil` makes a condition false, but other values make a condition true, test:

`print(not nil)`         --> `true`
`print(not not nil)`     --> `false`